# How do I make the mouse cursor appear automatically in the TextBox?

Tags: extjs

I have a textbox and a Save button. When I save one record, after that the mouse cursor should automatically appear in the textbox. So that, I don't have to use my Mouse or Keyboard Tab button.
I am using ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

The `focus()` method will do what you want.

Something like this should work:

```
Ext.getCmp('textboxID').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[focus](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#method-focus)** method of `textfield` appear cursor on the field.

**Code snippet:**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            //here we are getting the field and setting focus on it
            this.down('textfield[name=name]').focus();
        }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        vtype: 'email'
    }]
});
```

Here is the **[working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2maq)**.

Hope this will help/guide you.